# Efficient way to remove strings/characters from three columns and convert to a float in pandas

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I have a pandas data frame with three columns having a mixture of alphanumeric values in them. I want to:

1. efficiently remove the characters/strings in the alphanumeric values in columns `Price`, `Miles`, and `Weight`.
2. Convert the resulting values to a float

See below for an example...

```
import pandas as pd

cars_info = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
            'Price': ['22000$','25000$','27000$','35000$'],
            'Miles': ['1200 miles', '10045 miles', '22103 miles', '1110 miles'],
            'Weight': ['2500 lbs','2335 lbs','2110 lbs','2655 lbs']}

df = pd.DataFrame(cars_info, columns = ['Brand', 'Price','Miles','Weight'])

df.dtypes # returns `object` data type for columns Price, Miles and Weight
```

Desired result

```
Brand, Price($), Miles(in miles), Weight(lbs) 
Honda Civic,22000,1200, 2500
Toyota Corolla, 25000, 10045, 2335
Ford Focus, 27000, 22103, 2110
Audi A4, 35000, 1110, 2655
```

My attempt

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r'\D', '').astype(float)
```

Comment: @ALollz:   did you attempt this ?  your attempt is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem. You could `.str.replace` the labels you don't care about, or `.str.split` if you know the number is always the first thing before a space, for instance.

In this case it looks like you can `extract` whatever looks like a number `([\d\.]+)`, and then use `pd.to_numeric` to cast that to a numeric type.

```
for col in ['Price', 'Miles', 'Weight']:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col].str.extract('([\d\.]+)', expand=False))
```

---

```
print(df)
#            Brand  Price  Miles  Weight
#0     Honda Civic  22000   1200    2500
#1  Toyota Corolla  25000  10045    2335
#2      Ford Focus  27000  22103    2110
#3         Audi A4  35000   1110    2655

df.dtypes
#Brand     object
#Price      int64
#Miles      int64
#Weight     int64
#dtype: object
```

Comment: your approach returns the repetitive values (first number) in each of the Price, Miles and Weight columns.

Comment: It returns the first numeric-like value in each cell, which given it looks like you only ever expect 1 "number" in each cell it returns that.

Comment: my desired output for example in Price column is 22000, 25000,27000 and 35000, but what I am getting with your code is 22000, 22000, 22000 and 22000.

Comment: I mean I'm clearly not getting that result, so either you're copying something wrong or your sample data aren't the same as your real problem

Comment: you are correct works with this sample data but not for my original data.. I guess it just one of those weird python things.. Thanks for your attempt

Answer (score 0):

**step 1:** focus on the int conversion per relevant columns:

```
brands = df['Brand']
df = df.drop(columns=['Brand'])
```

**step 2:** maintain ints only:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'\D', '')).astype(int)


    Price   Miles   Weight
0   22000   1200    2500
1   25000   10045   2335
2   27000   22103   2110
3   35000   1110    2655
```

**step 3: combine:** (as in concat)

```
pd.concat([brands,df],  axis=1)


    Brand           Price   Miles   Weight
0   Honda Civic     22000   1200    2500
1   Toyota Corolla  25000   10045   2335
2   Ford Focus      27000   22103   2110
3   Audi A4        35000    1110    2655


df.dtypes
Price     int32
Miles     int32
Weight    int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks for your attempt,  is there a more efficient way? Assuming I have 5000 columns, I was thinking of a more robust way of iterating through the columns and then remove non-numeric part of every column with alphanumeric values. Thanks

Comment: can you define those who can be left out? (I mean 5K columns that's a lot) Alternatively. what id you look for words that should be removed like $, miles etc and then remove those specifics. would that work?

Comment: I like your approach, however, I don't think it will be practical to leave out, let say 3000 columns just because we want to remove strings in 3 columns. In a nutshell, do you have an alternative to your step 1? I am thinking something along the lines of a for-loop and if else statement.